# FIND_IN_SET duplica los resultados cuando lo pongo 2 veces

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer una concatenación de unas ciudades dependiendo de una cadena delimitada por comas que está almacenada en otra tabla. Tengo mis dos tablas

```
USERS
___________
ID   |   NAME     |  PRI_COUNTRIES    |   SEC_COUNTRIES
1        ALBERTO     1,2                  3,4

COUNTRIES
___________
ID   |  NAME
1       México
2       Colombia
3       Venezuela
4       Perú
```

Esta es la query que estoy usando

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(C.NAME) 'PRIMARY_COUNTRIES',
GROUP_CONCAT(CC.NAME) 'SECONDARY_COUNTRIES',
U.NAME AS 'USERNAME'
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN COUNTRIES C ON FIND_IN_SET( C.ID, U.PRI_COUNTRIES )
INNER JOIN COUNTRIES CC ON FIND_IN_SET( CC.ID, U.SEC_COUNTRIES )
```

El resultado es

```
PRIMARY_COUNTRIES
México, Colombia, México, Colombia
SECONDARY_COUNTRIES
Venezuela, Perú, Venezuela, Perú
NAME
ALBERTO
```

Yo esperaba

```
PRIMARY_COUNTRIES
México, Colombia
SECONDARY_COUNTRIES
Venezuela, Perú
NAME
ALBERTO
```

No entiendo por que si son 2 alias distintos a `COUNTRIES`, de hecho si quito un `JOIN` y un `GROUP_CONCAT`, osea, solo traigo `PRIMARY_COUNTRIES` Si funciona, sin duplicar los resultados, Que más necesito para conseguir el objetivo?

Comment: No es el '`FIND_IN_SET` sino el `JOIN` lo que te lo duplica. Basicamente mapea 1 con 3 y 4 y luego 2 con 3 y 4. No recuerdo si funcionaba pero prueba a poner un DISTINCT dentro del GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: Ya te hubieras ganado la respuesta JDev, funcionó :3

Comment: Por favor, pongan la solución como respuesta para que los demás sepan a futuro cómo se soluciona. Gracias!

Comment: Puesto como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es el `FIND_IN_SET` sino el `JOIN` quien lo duplica. Básicamente te mapea 1 con 3 y 4 y luego 2 con 3 y 4.

Prueba con un `DISTINCT` dentro del `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT C.NAME) 'PRIMARY_COUNTRIES',
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CC.NAME) 'SECONDARY_COUNTRIES',
U.NAME AS 'USERNAME'
FROM USERS U
INNER JOIN COUNTRIES C ON FIND_IN_SET( C.ID, U.PRI_COUNTRIES )
INNER JOIN COUNTRIES CC ON FIND_IN_SET( CC.ID, U.SEC_COUNTRIES )
```